# setInterval is using useState variable default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a Analytics REACT Application where Analytics API is called every 15 seconds to get the updated value. For this I am using few useState variables as:

```
const Date_Var = new Date()
const [FilterType, setFilterType] = useState(3)
const [Month, setMonth] = useState(("0" + (Date_Var.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2))
const [Year, setYear] = useState(currentYear)
const [MonthYear, setMonthYear] = useState(currentYear)
const [CurrentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(Date_Var.getFullYear()+"-"+ ("0" + (Date_Var.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0" + Date_Var.getDate()).slice(-2))
const [FromDate, setFromDate] = useState(Date_Var.getFullYear()+"-"+ ("0" + (Date_Var.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0" + Date_Var.getDate()).slice(-2))
const [ToDate, setToDate] = useState(Date_Var.getFullYear()+"-"+ ("0" + (Date_Var.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0" + Date_Var.getDate()).slice(-2))
```

These all useState variables change whenever user tries to change.

To call API every 10 seconds, I am using the setInterval in useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (FilterType == 1){
            LoadAnnualStats(Year)
        } else if (FilterType == 2){
            LoadMonthlyStats(MonthYear+"-"+Month)
        } else if (FilterType == 3){
            LoadDayStats(CurrentDate)
        } else if (FilterType == 4){
            LoadCustomStats(FromDate, ToDate)
        }
        if (FilterType == 5){
            LoadDayStats(yesterday)
        }
    }, 10000)
    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    }, [])
```

Now, the issue I am facing is that setInterval is using the default values for example FilterType is always taken as 3 instead of 1, 2 or 4 and similary other useState variables are sending default values as well and it is failing things.

When I try to log outside of useEffect, I get the latest values but in setInterval on log and on API calls I get the default values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLoE5.png)

What should be the problem here?

Comment: `FromDate, ToDate, ... ` etc, are all dependency for your `useEffect`,  your doing `[]`  So your basically keeping the initial values, add these to the dependency.  `}, [FromDate,...,etc..]`

Comment: https://medium.com/@anandsimmy7/stale-closures-and-react-hooks-ea60689a3544